# window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL Not calling callBack function

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, cordova-plugins

I am working on app,i have to choose picture from gallery and camera,so i am using **cordova camera plugin**,I am using **destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI** its working fine,Now i want to convert URI to file object,So i am using **File plugin V1.2.0**, I tried to convert to file using     **window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileUrl, onResolveSuccess, onFail);** its calling the on fail function,but i am having FileURl the path of image, I am choosing picture from my local desktop in stimulator and i am getting the path like **file:///C:/Users/some/Desktop/some/some.jpg**, even i tried in Mobile device its not working,i am trying to find solution with this from last 4 days need help

```
//select picture from gallery

function selectGallery() {
var pictureSource = navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
var destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType;
    navigator.camera.getPicture(onSuccessGallery,onFailGallery, {
    quality: 50,
    sourceType: pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY,
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI

});
}

function onSuccessGallery(fileURL) {
// i am getting fileURL: file:///C:/Users/some/Desktop/some/some.jpg
var Image
Image = document.getElementById('Image');
Image.src = fileURL;
window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(fileURL, onResolveSuccess, onFail);
}

function onResolveSuccess (fileEntry)
{
   alert("fileEntry");
}

 function onFail(e)
{
   alert("Error");
}
```

Comment: Can you check your android platform version?

Comment: yes mine is Android 6.0.1 i tested it,even in my iphone 5c, i implemented its not working

Comment: update the file plugin and try

Comment: @NagarajM What is your fileURL value? Ideally the first argument in window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL should be a directory available in device.

Comment: @file:///C:/Users/some/Desktop/some/some.jpg